# Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (BTC_TASK)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I'm coding a piece of firmware code for a Tensilica MCU, the ESP32 S3, and found the following canary error when running:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception). 
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (BTC_TASK) 
Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x40379749  PS      : 0x00060836  A0      : 0x3fcecf60  A1      : 0x3fcecea0  
A2      : 0x3fcedd08  A3      : 0x3fced2a0  A4      : 0x00000015  A5      : 0x0000ff00  
A6      : 0x00000015  A7      : 0x3fced1c4  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x3fcc39a0  
A10     : 0x3fcc398b  A11     : 0x3c14beb0  A12     : 0x00000015  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x00060820  A15     : 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x00000004  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400556d5  LEND    : 0x400556e5  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffffa  

Backtrace:0x40379746:0x3fcecea00x3fcecf5d:0x3fcecf90  |<-CORRUPTED
```

Can anyone here advise on what this may mean, without any additional info?

Answer (score -2):

This Guru meditation shows this info `EXCVADDR: 0x00000000` meaning a NULL result when performing memory operations. In laymen's terms simply means the firmware code runout of all stack memory.

To solve it one needs to:

- add a pSRAM IC into the electronics
- optimize the code with less stack memory variable allocation

use the code below to print available memory at runtime to a Serial port

```
  Serial.println("[APP] Free memory: " + String(esp_get_free_heap_size()) + " bytes");
```